# ¿Cómo solucionar este error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3?

Tags: java, array

Después de investigar bastante, no consigo dar con la solución para el siguiente error y no sé qué es lo que puede estar provocándolo. El error en cuestión es el siguiente:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Y el código que he escrito es:

```
            for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
                int f = i+1;
                int g = j+1;
                if (m2[i][j] == 1){
                    if (i < x && j <x){
                        if (m2[i][j+1] == 0 || m2[i+1][j] == 0) // Aquí me marca el error.
                        m2[i][j]= 0;
                        m1[i][j]= r;
                    }
                    else {
                        m2[i][j]=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

El error me lo da concretamente en la línea que pone:

```
if (m2[i][j+1] == 0 || m2[i+1][j] == 0)
```

El tamaño de la matriz `m2` es `x` (definido en otra parte del código).

Comment: Aclarar que el tamaño de la matriz es X, que ya está declarado en el código, lo que he puesto es solo un fragmento.

Comment: ¿es una matriz cuadrada de ancho y alto = x?, ¿que es r? ya que siempre  que se cumpla el *primer* if, se asigna..

Answer (score 3):

En el bucle cuando la variable j vale `j = x - 1`, accedes a la posicion del array  `j + 1`. Si sustituimos vemos que realmente estás accediendo a `x - 1 + 1`, que es `x`.

Es decir, que al final estás accediendo a la posición `m2[i][x]` que está fuera del array.

Answer (score 2):

Fíjate el recorrido que haces en estos for...

```
     for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
```

Si te das cuenta la "j" recorre hasta el ultimo elemento de tu matriz entonces cuando j=x-1 accede a la ultima posición de la matriz y si intentas hacer j+1 ese elemento ya no existe por eso te indica el indexoutofbounds.
De igual manera en el i+1 pero se lanza primero la excepción de la j.
La solución podría ser que cambies el segundo if

```
       if (i < x-1 && j < x-1)
```

Pero necesitaría saber que es lo que intentas hacer para ver si es una buena solución.